# Formatting the date in unix/linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I would like unix's date's day of the month format to be in the format 1 or 2 etc. instead of 01, 02. Is there anyway to achieve this?
For example

```
date +"%h%d%H:%M" yields Jun0100:30
```

ps. The reason I need this is I'm checking against another time format which is formatted the way I want it namely

```
Jun100:30
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system

```
date +"%h%-d%H:%M"
```

prints

```
Jun109:50
```

prefix the `%d` with `-`: `%-d`

Comment: @OldPro Be really "Pro"! - The OP wants remove the leading zero - and the answer gives the solution - and you know this. I upvote your answer - and asking all - please upvote "OldPro's" answer! :) ;) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
date +"%h%-e%H:%M"
```

will get you `Jun100:30`. Is that what you want?